# Is it possible to animate UIEdgeInsets?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uitextfield, uiviewanimationtransition

I've been trying to animate a change in `UIEdgeInsets`. I've already tried using `UIView.animateWithDuration` and the insets just jump to the final values. Does anyone know if this a property that can't be animated? Or better yet, is anyone aware of a way to animate insets?

As an example:

```
// Starting inset values
self.searchField.placeHolderInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 110, bottom: 0, right: 10)

// Animation block
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {
        self.searchField.placeHolderInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 18, bottom: 0, right: 10)
})
```

Instead of moving 92 pixels to the left over 0.1 seconds, the text jumps to the final value. `searchField` is a `UITextField` and `.placeHolderInset` is the UIEdgeInset being used to determine the insets for the `UITextField`'s placeholder text.

**EDIT:** Another way to achieve the desired effect is by changing the `UITextField`'s `.textAlignment` from `.Center` to `.Left` but that won't animate either.

Comment: did u try to add more value to animate duration?... suppose 0.4

Comment: Try calling `self.searchField.layoutIfNeeded()` inside the animation block. Does that help?

Comment: @robmayoff, you, my good sir, are brilliant. That did the trick. Want to post is as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the view, inside of the animation block.