# Animate a change to the values in a UITextView's textContainerInset

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uitextview, animatewithduration

In my application I'm using a custom toolbar (just another `UIView`) at the top of the screen; it sits above a `UITextView`. I'm using *auto layout*.

Because I'm using this custom toolbar - I'm doing the following to make the `UITextView` look correct with respect to margins and scroll indicators:

```
// the height of the custom toolbar is 55
_textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(68, 5, 8, 5);
_textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(54, 0, 0, 0);
```

When the keyboard is showing, I remove the toolbar. When the keyboard is dismissed, I show the toolbar. I animate the change of the toolbar's position, like this:

```
- (void)animateTopToolbarOn
{
    [self.view removeConstraints:_topToolbarOffScreenVerticalConstraints];
    [self.view addConstraints:_topToolbarOnScreenVerticalConstraints];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

    // this is the bit I need to get right:
    _textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(68, 5, 8, 5);
    _textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(54, 0, 0, 0);
}

- (void)animateTopToolbarOff
{
    [self.view removeConstraints:_topToolbarOnScreenVerticalConstraints];
    [self.view addConstraints:_topToolbarOffScreenVerticalConstraints];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

    // this is the bit I need to get right:
    _textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 5, 8, 5);
    _textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

// For reference:
id topGuide = self.topLayoutGuide;
_topToolbarOffScreenVerticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_topToolbar][topGuide]"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                               views:views];

_topToolbarOnScreenVerticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                              constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[topGuide][_topToolbar]"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                              views:views];
```

The animation of the toolbar's position / constraints, works fine, as you'd expect.

The problem is changing the values of the `textContainerInset`.

Note: I know that I could put the change in the *completion block* of the animation. Whilst it makes a difference to how it looks/feels, the problem remains, the change to the top margin occurs instantly, so it appears as a *jump*. It's jarring.

I could anchor the top constraint of the `UITextView` to the bottom constraint of the toolbar; then I wouldn't need to change either the `textContainerInset` values or the `scrollIndicatorInsets`. However, if I do that, the text won't scroll *underneath* the toolbar. I want to avoid this fallback position, if possible.

Any ideas?

I don't think the values of the `textContainerInset` can be animated? It doesn't match with [the animatable UIView properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW2)...

How can I achieve this setup using a plain `UIView` acting as a custom toolbar, which animates on and off the screen, to which the margins of the `UITextView` respond to?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: Not from me - I haven't made any changes to this. I think that, because the values of `textContainerInset` *cannot* be animated, I have to work within the restrictions that I've described above.

Comment: Running into this myself—the Apple docs you posted don't list `UIEdgeInset` as being animatable (which `textContainerInset` is); however, this link seems to suggest you can indeed animate `UIEdgeInset` changes: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30136973/482557. So, I'm wondering if it's something particular to `UITextView`. Tried mucking about with its `layoutManager` and `textContainer` but that's not working either, and I'm calling `layoutIfNeeded`.